# Is it better for a person's stomach to have 1 big meal or 2 small meals? Does this change as a person gets older?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

Is it better for a person's stomach to have 1 big meal or 2 small meals? Does this change as a person gets older.
Also what about water? Is it the same way or different and why?

Comment: How do you define 'better'?

Comment: "*Also what about water?*" Try drinking all you daily water in one go. Your body will instantly let you know it's not okay with that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is both unclear (see comment by @user438383) and seemingly asking for a medical opinion. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Ask] effective and appropriate questions on this site and then delete or [edit] your post accordingly.